# PHP Password reset token. Parsing the reset url?

Tags: php, passwords, token, reset

I have a question regarding my password reset link. So far I have managed to generate a random token using sha256, append it to the URL - domain.com/reset/randomtoken - and email the link to the respective user. My question is, which function would I use to have this go to reset.php instead of it thinking there's a directory called domain.com/reset/randomtoken. Thanks in advance, I'm still a noobie at this.

Comment: You have to use [a `.htaccess` file and URL rewriting](http://www.google.co.jp/#hl=en&gs_nf=1&cp=10&gs_id=d4&xhr=t&q=htaccess+url+rewrite&pf=p&biw=1199&bih=1753&sclient=psy-ab&oq=htaccess+u&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=63f789925d8935f4) for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either configure your web server (Apache, nginx, etc) to redirect that path to your PHP file, or make your life easier and generate a link that looks like this instead:

```
domain.com/reset.php?token=randomtoken
```

Then use `$_GET['token']` to retrieve the value.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was trying to avoid any .htaccess directives. This is the exact function I was looking for. :)